Paramiko - SFTP server removes files before they are uploaded
I am using paramiko to send pdf and csv files to an sftp server.
The client is telling me that some files arrive on the server but I keep getting the error:
Failed to upload 180.pdf for order 180: [Errno 2] /home/trant.ch/180.pdf is not a valid file path
How can I make sure, that the file is uploaded and the code is not going forrward until it is done.
Also once the file is on the sftp Server, it gets removed immediately. That's part of the process.
This is my code snippet:
def upload_delivery_notes(access_token, orders, sftp_details):
    if sftp_details:
        host, port, username, password = sftp_details
        try:
            transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
            transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
            sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

            remote_path = "/home/trant.ch/"


            for order in orders:
                order_id = order['id']
                # Get the delivery note link
                documents = get_delivery_note_link(access_token, order_id)

                # Extract and save the PDF content
                for note in documents['entries']:
                    if note['type'] == 'delivery_note':
                        pdf_content = note['content']
                        pdf_filename = f"{order_id}.pdf"
                        save_pdf_locally(pdf_content, pdf_filename, order_id)
                        try:
                            print("Waiting before upload")
                            time.sleep(2)
                            
                            sftp.put(pdf_filename, remote_path + pdf_filename) 
                            time.sleep(2)
                            print("slept enough")
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(f"Failed to upload {pdf_filename} for order {order_id}: {e}")
                    else:
                        print(f"No delivery note for order {order_id} found")
            
            sftp.close()
            transport.close()
        
        except Exception as e:
            error_message = f"SFTP connection failed: {e}"

            print(error_message)
    else:
        print("No SFTP details provided")
        pass

    try:
        sftp.close()
    except:
        pass

    try:
        transport.close()
    except:
        pass

I would like to have security that the file is uploaded, because the next steps is to update orders in another system. Without confirmation I can't proceed.
I tried different libraries
I tried time.sleep(X) options
I tried debugging, but the error remains and it is not a constant error
